# Users are getting other user's session!

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, session

I have two .NET websites, which is setup to share sessions in-between via SQL db.

The website stores and retrieves session as using `session("MY_Session").add` and `Session("MY_Session")`.  What gets stored is basically a custom class with their username and name.

The parent website is setup in IIS using DefaultAppPool and then the secondary site is setup as virtual directory application in the same pool.

I am not quite sure how it is set up on SQL for the sessions as I did not put it in.

In the web.config for both applications, it is set as follows:

```
sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
sqlConnectionString="server=xxxxx;uid=uuuu;pwd=pppppp;Application Name=NNNNNN"/
```

Users are claiming that they sometimes open up their browser and go to the site and find that other people's  information (from within the same organisation) is appearing...

Anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong and what to do next please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a caching issue, if there is a proxy server involved -- make sure any personalised content is correctly flagged so that it is not shared between clients.

A header like this should improve matters:

> Cache-Control: private

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So that will hopefully force users' pc to refresh from the server but I am confused why they would grab someone else's session? I mean, these people are claiming that they didn't enter any username or password and are able to navigate the whole site and access other people's information comepletely! almost like a session hijack

Comment: I am safe to assume they are using different pc's?

Comment: @Ichirichi It may be the case that the session isn't being shared, but content generated based on the session has been cached by an intermediate proxy and given to a different client without the request going all the way back to your server.